# discrepancies in fisher.test in R

Tags: r, comparison, anova, chi-squared

I though i was running the same test twice, but it turns out the results are different.

Firstly i created a contingency table from my data:

```
> SAtab1 <- table(dt2$ACE_SA_BIN, dt2$IHD_other_healthy)
> SAtab1
   
      0   1   2
  0 345 577  29
  1  10  25   2
```

and then i run the fisher test:

```
> fisher.test(SAtab1, workspace = 2e8, simulate.p.value=TRUE)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  SAtab1
p-value = 0.2969
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Then i saw somewhere code, where they passed a matrix instead of the contingency table. SO i create a matrix:

```
> SAtab2 <- 
+   matrix(c(345,10,577,25,29,2),
+          nrow = 2,
+          dimnames = list(Gender = c("no", "yes"),
+                          Illness =c("no illness","other than IHD", "HD")))
> SAtab2
      Illness
Gender no illness other than IHD HD
   no         345            577 29
   yes         10             25  2
```

and run the fisher.test again:

```
> fisher.test(SAtab2, workspace = 2e8, simulate.p.value=TRUE)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  SAtab2
p-value = 0.2829
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

How is it possible that the test do not yield the same results? Where does the minor deviance come from?

Answer (score 2):

It is not the `class` (table vs matrix) that is the problem, but the `simulate.p.value` is TRUE,  e.g. if we run the same data with `simulate.p.value` multiple times, it returns different p value.  According to ?fisher.test

> simulate.p.value - a logical indicating whether to compute p-values by Monte Carlo simulation, in larger than
> 2
> ×
> 2
> tables

```
> fisher.test(SAtab2, workspace = 2e8, simulate.p.value=TRUE)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  SAtab2
p-value = 0.3088
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

> fisher.test(SAtab2, workspace = 2e8, simulate.p.value=TRUE)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  SAtab2
p-value = 0.3018
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

whereas it will give the same output otherwise

```
> lst1 <- replicate(5, fisher.test(SAtab2, workspace = 2e8, simulate.p.value=FALSE), simplify = FALSE)

> all.equal(lst1[[1]], lst1[[2]])
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(lst1[[1]], lst1[[3]])
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(lst1[[1]], lst1[[5]])
[1] TRUE
```